# Error using SAAJ on WildFly 8.2

Tags: java, soap, wildfly, saaj

I am workling on WilfFly web application that send a file to a web service using SOAP and Java SAAJ.

I am facing this error (on woodstox-core-asl-4.4.0.jar):

```
12:02:46,927 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-24) 
Interceptor for {http://wscmis.pms.vr.it/}WSChemistry has thrown exception,
unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error reading XMLStreamReader.

Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '-' 
(code 45) in prolog; expected '<' at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
```

This is my method which call the WS:

```
public JSONObject invokeWS(String WSURL, String metodo, Map<String,String> params, String namespace){
    MessageFactory factory;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    JSONObject jsonResult=null;

    try {
        factory=MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message=factory.createMessage(); //Creo il messaggio SOAP
        SOAPPart soapPart=message.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope=soapPart.getEnvelope(); //Prendo l'envelope e poi il body (dell'header chissenefrega)
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("com", namespace); //Metto il namespace nell'envelope, Enrico's style
        SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
        header.detachNode();
        SOAPBody body=envelope.getBody();

        String elemento="com:"+metodo;
        QName bodyName=new QName(elemento); //Mi preparo un elemento da mettere nel body
        SOAPBodyElement bodyElement=body.addBodyElement(bodyName);

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if( !entry.getKey().equals("filedocpms") && !entry.getKey().equals("ctype") && !entry.getKey().equals("nomefile")) { //Se sono attributi che non hanno a che fare con l'allegato li metto normalmente nel messaggio SOAP
                QName name=new QName( entry.getKey() ); //Due elementi figli da mettere nell'elemento pms:computer creato prima
                SOAPElement symbol=bodyElement.addChildElement(name);
                symbol.addTextNode( entry.getValue() );             
            }
        }

        byte[] binario=params.get("filedocpms").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        File f=new File("Test");
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(f, binario);
        FileDataSource fds=new FileDataSource(f);

        DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(fds);
        AttachmentPart attachment = message.createAttachmentPart(dataHandler);
        attachment.setContentId( params.get("nomefile") );
        message.addAttachmentPart(attachment);

        java.net.URL url=new java.net.URL(WSURL); //Preparo URL e stream per inviare il messaggio SOAP
        java.net.URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        message.writeTo(conn.getOutputStream()); //Scrivo il messaggio SOAP nello stream
        java.io.BufferedReader rd=new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); //Dalla connessione prendo l'input stream per leggere i risultati

        String inline="";
        while ((inline=rd.readLine()) != null) {
         sb.append(inline);
        }

        JSONObject xmlJSONObj=XML.toJSONObject(sb.toString()); //Facccio un JSON Dall'XML ritornato dal WS
        jsonResult=xmlJSONObj.getJSONObject("soap:Envelope").getJSONObject("soap:Body").getJSONObject("ns2:"+metodo+"Response"); //Prendo la parte del JSON che mi interessa
    } 
    catch (SOAPException soape) {
        soape.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        mue.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonResult; 
 }
```

Basically it receive some parameters from the params Map object. The parameter filedocpms is the binary file in a byte array, which I put in the attachment part after some operatins with Apache Commons IO.

I am stuck I don't know what to do, any help is really appreciated.

EDIT:
    I used SOAPConnection in this way:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory=SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection connection=soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
java.net.URL endpoint=new URL(WSURL);

SOAPMessage response=connection.call(message, endpoint);
connection.close();
System.out.println( response.getSOAPHeader() );
System.out.println( response.getSOAPBody() );
```

But the two System.out print me this and the error still remains:

```
09:41:12,758 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) null
09:41:12,759 INFO  [stdout] (default task-24) [soap:Body: null]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that you are not setting the correct `Content-Type` when sending the request. If you want to use SAAJ, then you should use the `javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection` API (instead of `java.net.URL`), which takes care of setting the appropriate HTTP headers.